# Meteor.js Display all the users with their corresponding Profile Picture

Tags: javascript

See below my code. Currently it only displays the users name. My question is how to display all names of the user and its corresponding profile picture. This is for the admin side.

```
Template.portfolio.onCreated(function(){
this.subscribe("userData");
this.subscribe("profile");
Session.setDefault("searchUser","");
});


Template.portfolio.helpers({
userdata:function(){
  var keyword  = Session.get("searchUser");
return Meteor.users.find({"username": {'$regex' : '.*' + keyword + '.*'}}).fetch();
}
});

Template.portfolio.events({
"keyup #txtSearchStud": function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
Session.set("searchUser",$("#txtSearchStud").val());
}
});
```